# Multi-Process in AutoIt

Tags: multiprocessing, autoit

I have a program that download links from a list in and edit box. I want to create a button "Download"/"Pause" to run and interrupt the download function. But I don't know.

How to create a multi-process program with AutoIt?

Answer (score 0):

Start a sub process using Run, and make sure you store the pid. Then you need some method of interprocess communication. There are loads of ways of doing this. The following are pretty common: Message windows (with _SendMessage and WM_COPYDATA), TCP, named pipes and databases.

In your case a message window is probably the most suitable. It's very easy to setup using entirely standard AutoIt functions. A good example of using it is [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/119502-solved-wm-copydata-x64-issue/).